# Show that $\int_a^b cf = c \int_a^b f$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Let be $f$ and $cf$ integrable functions on the interval $[a,b ]$ where $c$ is a constant with $c<0$.

Show that: $$\int_a^b cf = c \int_a^b f.$$ I know that there is a different approach where you directly use $\sup$ and $\inf$. However, I want to know if the following approach is correct:

We already know from lecture that there exists a partition $P$ such that $U(f, P)- L(f, P) < \frac{\epsilon}{-c}$, where $U, L$ are the corresponding *Darboux*-sums and $\epsilon>0$.

Rearranging yields: 
$$cL(f, P)-cU(f,P)= U(cf,P)-cU(f,P) < \epsilon.$$ This inequality still holds with increasing refinement of $P$. Hence, taking the $\sup$ of both *Darboux*-sums we get $\int_a^b cf - c \int_a^b f <\epsilon$ as both functions $f$ and $cf$ are integrable on the interval $[a,b ]$. This is equivalent to  $\int_a^b cf = c \int_a^b f$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Presumably $c$ is a constant, and not an arbitrary function?  Your question does not make that clear.

Comment: @XanderHenderson, $c$ is a constant. I made an edit.

Comment: I think that we can rewrite the integral as the sum and multiply it with a constant, take it inside the sum and take it back to an integral form. That should do it.

Comment: @VukStojilkovic, I want to know if my particular approach is correct.